# Sci-fi book about 'zombie' creatures

Tags: story-identification, books, undead

I'm looking for a book that I read a few years ago (maybe 4 years). I'm not sure of what year it was, but I don't think that it was an old book.
I remember it vaguely but I wrote down everything I know.

The book began by describing the life of a police officer in England, then there was a part about some young people in a graveyard, seeing something (I only remember that there was a chapter about something with a graveyard, that the zombie thing began there).

Then a person became a zombie (I don't think that they used the word zombie, but something else), he first got headaches and his eyes hurt. He then scratched his eyes out and that happened to all of the victims who also became zombies.

It was hard to kill them, but the police shot them in the head (I think) and it worked. The police even tried to ask higher authorities for help (don't remember who) but they refused or didn't answer (again not sure).

The plot was that the police was struggling to get the situation under control, but at the end they did, but it ended by saying that the policeman (I think that it was him but I'm not sure) had severe headaches and his eyes hurt. Which indicated that he will become a "zombie".

It wasn't an apocalypse, the 'zombie' problem was just in that specific town.

I remember something about a stone, I think a green one. It had something to do with the whole zombie thing. I'm not sure how, just remembered the stone. It was mentioned in the beginning of the book.

I read the book in Polish, but it was translated from English. I remember that the names of the characters and streets/ towns were English.

- There weren't any vampires or other kind of mystical creatures.
- There wasn't any mention of the wars (WW1 or WW2) or anything.
- The book wasn't thick, it had around 200-300 pages. (I compared it with the first Harry Potter book.)
- I don't think it was a part of a series.
- I don't remember what was on the cover.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [*Death Day*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1803702.Death_Day) by Shaun Huston (AKA Robert Neville), it's one I read years ago but I'm a bit spotty on the details.

It does set off with a policeman in a small UK town and the struggles of his everyday life. Two workers in the cemetery accidentally unearth an unplotted grave and find a mysterious medallion. Over the next few hours a zombie outbreak happens and the police have to start shooting - I think they couldn't get outside help due to a bridge coming down (don't they always in horror stories?)

The policeman's friend and colleague gets infected and gets headache and sore eyes, he realises he's changing so he goes on the run into the country to try and avoid being shot.

A key point that might help you remember:-

He goes to jumpstart an abandoned car but he realises it's a Lada so he leaves it and shambles on down the country lane while thinking to himself

> "even the undead have some standards"

[image]